# How can I add condition that required or not in select vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My component vue is like this :

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required @change="changeLocation">
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>\
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props: ['type'],
        ....
    };
</script>
```

I want to add condition in select

If type = 1, on the select not display required like this :

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selected" @change="changeLocation">
```

If type = 2, on the select display required like this :

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selected" required @change="changeLocation">
```

How can I do it?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind data to plain HTML attributes. It doesn't need to be a component property.

```
<select class="form-control" :required="type == 2" ...></select>
```

Doing this, the select element will only have the `required` attribute if `type == 2`.